# Pyspark How to create columns and fill True/False if rolling datetime record exists

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Data-set contains products with daily record but sometime it misses out so i want to create extra columns to show whether it exists or not in the past few days

i have conditions below

1. Create T-1, T-2 and so on columns and fill it with below
2. Fill T-1 with 1 the record exist, otherwise zero

Original Table :

```
Item    Cat    DateTime    Value
 A      C1     1-1-2021     10
 A      C1     2-1-2021     10
 A      C1     3-1-2021     10
 A      C1     4-1-2021     10
 A      C1     5-1-2021     10
 A      C1     6-1-2021     10
 B      C1     1-1-2021     20
 B      C1     4-1-2021     20
```

Expect Result :

```
Item    Cat    DateTime    Value   T-1   T-2  T-3    T-4    T-5
 A       C1     1-1-2021     10     0     0    0       0     0
 A       C1     2-1-2021     10     1     0    0       0     0      (T-1 is 1 as we have 1-1-2021 record)
 A       C1     3-1-2021     10     1     1    0       0     0
 A       C1     4-1-2021     10     1     1    1       0     0
 A       C1     5-1-2021     10     1     1    1       1     0
 A       C1     6-1-2021     10     1     1    1       1     1
 B       C1     1-1-2021     20     0     0    0       0     0
 B       C1     2-1-2021      0     1     0    0       0     0      (2-1-2021 record need to be created with value zero since we miss this from original data-set, plus T-1 is  1 as we have this record from original data-set)
 B       C1     3-1-2021      0     0     1    0       0     0
 B       C1     4-1-2021     20     0     0    1       0     0
 B       C1     5-1-2021      0     1     0    0       1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have the original table data stored in `original_data`, we can

1. create a temporary view to query with spark sql named `daily_records`
2. generate possible dates . This was done by identifying the amount of days between the min and max dates from the dataset then generating the possible dates using table generating function `explode` and `spaces`
3. generate all possible `item`, `date` records
4. join these records with the actual to have a complete dataset with values
5. Use spark sql to query the view and create the additional column using the left joins and `CASE` statements

```py
# Step 1
original_data.createOrReplaceTempView("daily_records")
# Step 2-4
daily_records = sparkSession.sql("""
WITH date_bounds AS (
   SELECT min(DateTime) as mindate, max(DateTime) as maxdate FROM daily_records
),
possible_dates AS (
   SELECT 
       date_add(mindate,index.pos) as DateTime 
   FROM 
       date_bounds
   lateral view posexplode(split(space(datediff(maxdate,mindate)),"")) index
),
unique_items AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT Item, Cat from daily_records
),
possible__item_dates AS (
   SELECT Item, Cat, DateTime FROM unique_items INNER JOIN possible_dates ON 1=1
),
possible_records AS (
   SELECT 
      p.Item,
      p.Cat,
      p.DateTime,
      r.Value
    FROM
      possible__item_dates p
    LEFT JOIN
      daily_records r on p.Item = r.Item and p.DateTime = r.DateTime
      
)
select * from possible_records

""")
daily_records.createOrReplaceTempView("daily_records")
daily_records.show()
# Step 5 - store results in desired_result

# This is optional, but I have chosen to generate the sql to create this dataframe

periods = 5 # Number of periods to check for
period_columns = ",".join(["""
    CASE
        WHEN t{0}.Value IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as `T-{0}`
""".format(i) for i in range(1,periods+1)])
period_joins = " ".join(["""
    LEFT JOIN
        daily_records t{0} on datediff(to_date(t.DateTime),to_date(t{0}.DateTime))={0} and t.Item = t{0}.Item
""".format(i) for i in range(1,periods+1)])

period_sql = """
SELECT
    t.*
    {0}
FROM
    daily_records t
 {1}
ORDER BY
   Item, DateTime
""".format(
    "" if len(period_columns)==0 else ",{0}".format(period_columns),
    period_joins
)
desired_result= sparkSession.sql(period_sql)
desired_result.show()
```

Actual `SQL` generated:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.Value IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as `T-1`,
    CASE
        WHEN t2.Value IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as `T-2`,
    CASE
        WHEN t3.Value IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as `T-3`,
    CASE
        WHEN t4.Value IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as `T-4`,
    CASE
        WHEN t5.Value IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as `T-5`
FROM
    daily_records t
 
    LEFT JOIN
        daily_records t1 on datediff(to_date(t.DateTime),to_date(t1.DateTime))=1 and t.Item = t1.Item
 
    LEFT JOIN
        daily_records t2 on datediff(to_date(t.DateTime),to_date(t2.DateTime))=2 and t.Item = t2.Item
 
    LEFT JOIN
        daily_records t3 on datediff(to_date(t.DateTime),to_date(t3.DateTime))=3 and t.Item = t3.Item
 
    LEFT JOIN
        daily_records t4 on datediff(to_date(t.DateTime),to_date(t4.DateTime))=4 and t.Item = t4.Item
 
    LEFT JOIN
        daily_records t5 on datediff(to_date(t.DateTime),to_date(t5.DateTime))=5 and t.Item = t5.Item

ORDER BY
   Item, DateTime
```

NB. `to_date` is optional if `DateTime` is already formatted as a `date` field or in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: See my other answer of how to use a udf to generate rows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221045/insert-extra-rows-in-query-result-sql/66228160#66228160

Comment: Thank you for your help, for the above SQL part, i got error : "Reference 't.DateTime' is ambiguous, could be: t.t, t1.t.; line 28 pos 45"

Comment: I'm updating the answer with the code to generate the missing rows

Comment: thank again for your effort  and help, i have another error "cannot resolve '`Item`' given input columns: [daily_records.day, daily_records.T-12, daily_records.T-10, daily_records.date, daily_records.T-13..."  from the updated script. Please kindly help again

Comment: @foy I just re-ran this code in a notebook and it works. I've also re-organized the answer so that it is easier for you to replicate the flow. Let me know if this works

Comment: @foy I am not sure where the columns `day` and `date` are derived on based on your question and my response. Are you referring to another query?

Comment: for step 2 when i ran it , it still produce "cannot resolve '`Item`' given input columns. any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230792/discussion-between-ggordon-and-foy).

Comment: I've sent a message in chat requesting debugging details